# I'm hosting my website from Heroku and cloudflare registrar - why does the first visit take so long to load?

Tags: heroku, cloudflare

What do I need to change in either Heroku or Cloudflare to get the page loaded quicker?
It takes way too long to load if I haven't visisted the site recently

Comment: What do you need to change? Well you haven't really told us anything about how your site is configured... how can we possibly answer that? Please read [ask].

Comment: Are you using free Heroku dynos? They go to sleep, so there's a cold start if they haven't been active for a while.